# GCP CloudFunctions "no available instance" error - will it be retried?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

We run a Cloud Function in production and every so often we get this error:

> "The request was aborted because there was no available instance."

This results in an HTTP 500 error response.

This is a known issue, and the cause seems to be that our traffic is scaling up very quickly and there are not enough function instances to handle the traffic.

This is an `event-driven` function. According to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries):

> Cloud Functions guarantees at-least-once execution of an event-driven function for each event emitted by an event source. However, by default, if a function invocation terminates with an error, the function will not be invoked again, and the event will be dropped.

My question is: will my function be retried when I get the error above? The documentation is confusing. Technically, we're getting an HTTP POST 500 error, so I don't know whether this function is being retried.

Edit: at this point, I do *not* have enabled retries for my CloudFunction. I'm asking this question to know whether I should enable retries.

Comment: It depends! How did you deployed your functions? If by command line, can you paste it. What the gen of Cloud Functions (gen1 or gen2)?

Comment: This is the command I use  (edited and simplified) `gcloud functions deploy my-function --entry-point=MyNamespace.MyClass --region=$_GCP_REGION  --source=./function/ --trigger-resource=projects/${PROJECT_ID}/databases/(default)/documents/docs/{docId} --trigger-event=providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.write --runtime=dotnet6`

Comment: @RohitKharche Thanks for answering my question. Your answer was not that helpful as it limited to dump the same documentation I had read several times. It did not offer any additional insight, practical experience or demo code. That is why I haven't upvoted it. Please stop chasing people for upvotes. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your valid suggestion. I have tagged you  to understand anything else i can  help you so that i can re work and update my answer. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Functions have retriable and not retriable errors. More on this check here:  **[Distinguish between retriable and fatal errors](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries#distinguish_between_retriable_and_fatal_errors)**

The error you are getting "The request was aborted because there was no available instance," is a HTTP 500 error, it generally means that there was an issue while processing the request which means this is a retriable error. So **Yes** your function will be retried.

Description from the **Retry on failure** checkbox on cloud function console says :

> If your function crashes for any reason, including bugs in your code, it will be retried for up to seven days if this box is checked. It is best used to make your function resilient to transient failures in your code.

Best practice to stop these unnecessary retries is to **[Make retryable event-driven functions idempotent](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries#make_retryable_event-driven_functions_idempotent)** and to **[Configure the retry policy](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries#configure_the_retry_policy)** as per your needs.

Also you can solve this problem by increasing the **[--max-instances](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--max-instances)** to handle the increasing traffic.

Comment: Hold on. My cloud function does not have "retries" enabled. What you have quoted is the description from the "Retry on failure". So if I understand correctly, these errors will be retried *if I have the 'Retry on failure'* check box ticked, and they won't otherwise?

Comment: @mkorman Yes. 

if you have the 'Retry on failure' check box ticked, they will be retried for 

retry-able errors.

Comment: And if I don't have that ticked? I assume they won't be retried? Thanks

Comment: That's was the meaning of my first comment. add the "--retry" on the Cloud Functions deployment and it will be OK